# continue the .each() loop in jQuery to show more search results

Tags: jquery, loops, search, return, break

I have search results I want to break down into chunks. I display sets of 10 results in an .each() loop and then break the loop when the results count is 10. If the user clicks a certain, more results should be displayed until 20 results show and so on. The loop stops correctly, but it doesn't continue (i.e., show more results), when the button is pressed. Wham am I doing wrong?

```
$("Document").each(function(index) {
  //code to display search result (not included) 
  if ( index % 10 === 0) {
    //stop the loop                             
    return false;          
    $("button#moreResults").click(function(event){
      //continue the loop of the each function
      return;
    });
  }
});//end of each function
```

Answer (score 0):

You never added the handler. Your `click()` call is *after* the `return`, so it's never executed. Try:

```
if ( index % 10 === 0) {
  $("button#moreResults").click(function(event){
    //continue the loop of the each function
    return;
  });

  //stop the loop                             
  return false;          
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but when I click on the button, the page refreshes and I don't get more results (the loop doesn't seem to be continuing).

Comment: You'll need to `return false;` and/or cancel the event within the handler. I assumed that was happening within your unseen "continue the loop" code.

Comment: You mean having a event.preventDefault(); inside the click() handler? I tried that. It still doesn't work. The return false seems to be overriding the return inside the click() handler. I'm stumped.

Comment: `return` statements don't "override" each other; the first one execute within a function simply ends the function. `return false;` should *replace* the `return;` statement inside your handler, after whatever else is going on in there.

Comment: That's the problem, no? return false is replacing the return; after it's completed. How do I get around that. Is it because the return; is nested? I still can't get it to work.

Comment: The `return false;` that you already have has *nothing* to do with the `return;` inside your `click()` function. One is executed immediately when your index hits `10`, the other is execute *if* that button is ever clicked. As for what else is/isn't working within the `click()` handler, I can't say, since you haven't shown the code.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Now I understand. Here's what I want to do. If the user clicks the "moreResults" button, I want this loop to continue iterating: $("Document").each(function(index)

Comment: Then you'll have to do something more elaborate, since by that time the loop has *exited*. There's no "continue iterating this loop" action available for JavaScript loops.